# Property type of overloaded weak reference is incompatible with type inherited from superclass because of a circular dependence

Tags: objective-c

I have a project structure in which:

• `ClassA` has a strong reference to `ClassB`

• `ClassAA` subclasses `ClassA` and has a strong reference to `ClassBB`

• `ClassB` has a weak reference to `ClassA` (named `state` and defined using `@class ClassA;`)

• `ClassBB` subclasses `ClassB` and overloads `state` to be `ClassAA` and uses `@class ClassAA;` to do so

Because of the overloaded `state` in `ClassBB`, the compiler can't tell that `ClassAA` is a subclass of `ClassA`. Thus, I get this warning:

#### Property type 'ClassAA *' is incompatible with type 'ClassA *' inherited from 'ClassB'`

How can I tell the compilter that I know what I'm doing, so the warning hides itself? Thanks for any advice. Below is the project structure that creates this warning:

**ClassA.h**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "ClassB.h"

@interface ClassA : NSObject

@property (strong)
ClassB* view;

@end
```

**ClassB.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@class ClassA;

@interface ClassB : UIView

@property (weak)
ClassA* state;

@end
```

**ClassAA.h** (inherits from ClassA)

```
#import "ClassA.h"
#import "ClassBB.h"

@interface ClassAA : ClassA

@property (strong)
ClassBB* view;

@end
```

**ClassBB.h** (inherits from ClassB)

```
#import "ClassB.h"
@class ClassAA;

@interface ClassBB : ClassB

@property (weak)
ClassAA* state; <-- Where the warning is occurring

@end
```

Comment: I'm just wondering-- Did you try with #import "ClassAA.H" rather than the `@class ClassAA` forward declaration?  I also wonder whether the property needs to be in the public @interface, in which case you could move it to the .m and get the same effect.

Comment: The only reason I'm using `@class` is because circular dependencies are not allowed. And I would prefer to keep it in the public @interface, sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is certainly a Quality-of-Implementation issue in the Clang Objective-C frontend; there's nothing wrong with your code, so the only question is how to trick the compiler into shutting up for a moment.

If you change your "ClassBB.h" to look like this, then it will compile without the warning — and `[[ClassBB new] state]` will still have the correct static type (namely `ClassAA*`, not `ClassA*`).

```
#import "ClassB.h"              // #imports required by is-a relationships

@interface ClassBB : ClassB @end          // define the is-a relationships

#import "ClassAA.h"            // #imports required by has-a relationships

@interface ClassBB()                     // define the has-a relationships
@property (weak) ClassAA* state;
@end
```

I don't think anyone would call this class layout a "best practice", but at least it's a clean-ish way to write this sort of not-really-circular dependency. (Notice the utter lack of `@class` declarations. IMO, `@class` is a code smell. This header file isn't responsible for defining `ClassAA`, so it should leave it up to "ClassAA.h" whether `ClassAA` is an Objective-C class, a typedef, a macro, or something else.)

Answer (score 1):

This is probably a good place to use a Protocol. 
Define a CassAConforming Protocol and a ClassBConforming Protocol. 
Make the properties id  And id in your base classes. 
Then make your subclasses conform to those protocols. 
This gives you the type checking Xcode wants to do for you and allows you to be flexible in the implementation.